# Accessing user input

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to create an e-commerce application and now I am at the part where I have to create the account management logic.I am trying to take advantage of the Membership API but I can't seem to find a way on how to proceed.

My application has two databases is the one containing all the tables for the e-commerce application and the second is the one generated by asp.net for using it with the Membership API.

I do not know how I can retrieve the data the user inputs.

This is what I am planning to do:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LogIn()
    {
        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if(Membership.ValidateUser(username , password))
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

Can anyone please give me an idea on how I can retrieve the user's input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to need to pass a model in. Let's say for example I've got a view with a form on it and it has the following fields:

```
<input type="textbox" id="username" name="username"/>
<input type="password" id="password" name="password"/>
```

Now I'm going to need a model to serialize this into:

```
public class LoginModel
{
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }
}
```

Now I'm going to want to receive that model into the action method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult LogIn(LoginModel model)
```

When the `POST` occurs, ASP.NET MVC will build the model for you out of the input fields inside the form.

Comment: ok but how are the username and password properties linked to my database considering the fact I want to use the database generated byt asp.net ASPNETDB.MDF?

Comment: This will very much depend on the database access technology that you are using. ASP.NET MVC has no database specific concepts. By default it uses a SQL Membership provider but you could of course write a custom one and store your accounts wherever you want.

Comment: so far I have used linq to sql doe the other database for the othe other database

Comment: The default Membership Provider that comes with ASP.NET MVC uses plain old ADO.NET. But as I said you could write a custom provider if the default one doesn't fit your needs.